# What is the syntax to pass array parameters in a symfony1 task?

Tags: php, command-line, symfony-1.4

I got a symfony 1.4 task (*I know, it is deprecated*) which take an array of int parameters :

```
new sfCommandOption('typical-days', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL | sfCommandOption::IS_ARRAY, 'Some description', array())
```

But now, I'm wondering how I have to use this parameter ? I tested this :

```
php symfony test:myTask --typical-days="7,5,8"
```

Or this :

```
php symfony test:myTask --typical-days 7,5,8
```

And some variants (using ; : - | as delimiters for example), but it is not working.

I checked the documentation, but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
php symfony test:myTask --typical-days=7 --typical-days=5 --typical-days=8
```

Comment: This is not very pretty but it works, thanks ! symfony 1.4 lack of informations about this.